# SQL query where clause is too long

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I've written an SQL query with a lot of 'or's in the 'where' clause:

i.e.

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1='a' or col1='b' or col1='c'...etc"
```

I'm trying to run a query in access via vb.net, but I keep getting "Query is too complex" error message.

I'm guessing I've hit some maximum limit. Anyone know a way around this, other than just to break it down into multiple queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) instead?

SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM Table1
WHERE Field1 IN('Val1','Val2', ....)

Answer (score 6):

If you query is that simple would you not be better using

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 in ('a','b','c')
```

but it would help to post the actual query so we can give a accurate answer

Answer (score 5):

You could use SQL `IN` operator instead having multiple `OR` conditions.

Comment: Works a charm. So simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN as in -

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 IN ('a','b','c','d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Many have stated that you should use the IN-operator instead, but when that is used together with constants I believe the optimiser simply converts that to an OR-operator.

Instead you could load a temporary table with your constants and **then** use the IN-operator with that table.

Comment: The question is tagged ms-access, sql is a generic tag, how do you see a temporary table working in MS Access?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes but the IN operator does solve my problem.

Comment: @Remou: I don't necessarily mean #table or @table, a static table just used for this purpose works just as well.

Comment: So, turn on Jet/ACE SHOWPLAN and see what the optimizer says. I really don't think it works the way you say, but it's your assertion, so by my guest and prove that you're correct.